# How to combine long list of data frames in R

Tags: r

I have long list of data frames (e.g., 100s) with names d1,d2,d3,..d100. I want to combine them in r as df <- cbind(d1:d100)? is there any efficient way of combining them except writing all column names?

Comment: `do.call(cbind,d)`

Comment: you don't want colnames to be added? you can set `names(df) = NULL`

Comment: It is often better to work with lists of data.frames. See gregor's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) for some tips.

Answer (score 3):

You could first pack all your data frames into a list and then `cbind` them using `do.call`. Here I am assuming your data frames are called d1, d2, ... and that they all have the same number of rows:

```
## Sample data:
d1 <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 4:6)
d2 <- data.frame(C = 7:9)
d3 <- data.frame(D = 10:12, E = 13:15)

## Put them into a list:
myList <- lapply(1:3, function(ii){get(paste0("d", ii))})

## Combine them into one big data frame:
myDataFrame <- do.call('cbind', myList)

myDataFrame 
#   A B C  D  E
# 1 1 4 7 10 13
# 2 2 5 8 11 14
# 3 3 6 9 12 15
```

Comment: Thanks. All sorted!